# Kali linux GUI won't start(among other things)

Tags: kali

I have the ARM version of Kali Linux installed on my Raspberry pi 2. I've been using it without any issue for about a week but when I went to start it last time I typed in the log in info and it just gave me a blinking line in the top left corner of the screen. So I rebooted the Pi and now Kali only runs in command line and for some reason the file system is now read only.

Do I need to do a complete reinstall or is there a better way to fix this?

Comment: Did you try `startx` once you logged in?

Comment: Yes I tried that, though now I can't enter any input, it's not command-line, it just has a blinking curser in the top left corner

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but the easiest thing will probably be to reinstall. If you can't get any action it may be easiest. But first check your keyboard. Can you ssh? Do you need to back things up?

Comment: When you do re-install: I recommend against Kali on the pi unless you are an experienced linux user (you do not count as such) or don't have any choice because it is for a course.  Anything you can do on Kali you can do on Raspbian, it is just a matter of installing the right software, etc.

Comment: @goldilocks  It was just a little experiment, but seeing as it didn't work i've installed raspbian and will just install the SE-toolkit the hardway.